# Slurping http://foobar.mp3 that redirects to http://fizzbar.mp3 in Clojure

Tags: java, http, clojure, download, slurp

I am trying to programatically download mp3 files from [this rss feed](http://podcast.menlo.church/feed/).
When I open an url such as: http://menlochurch.podbean.com/mf/feed/5gv2gb/170219_jortberg.mp3
it redirects to an url like: http://s62.podbean.com/pb/67f34563539acbe87b9566ecc5738d57/58aeff8e/data4/fs145/948579/uploads/170219_jortberg.mp3

If I `curl` the first url it downloads an empty file.

If I `curl -L` the first url it correctly downloads the file.

If I `curl` the second url it correctly downloads the file.

If I `slurp` the first url in Clojure it downloads something that looks like an mp3 (is big and has no legible text) but is unplayable and not the same as the output from `curl -L`.

If I `slurp` the second url in Clojure it also downloads something that looks like an mp3 (is big and has no legible text) but is unplayable and not the same as the output from `curl -L` and is identical to the output from the previous `slurp`.

`➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ ls -l *.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 38038533 Feb 23 08:32 curl-url1.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 38038533 Feb 23 08:37 curl-url2.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam        0 Feb 23 08:45 curl-without-L.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 67144297 Feb 23 08:31 slurp-url1.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 67144297 Feb 23 08:31 slurp-url2.mp3`

As you can see whatever I'm slurping, is almost twice as big as what I'm curling.

I don't know what to make of this, am I using `slurp` in an inappropriate context?  Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`slurp` is for strings so won't work with binary data.

```
user=> (doc slurp)
-------------------------
clojure.core/slurp
([f & opts])
  Opens a reader on f and reads all its contents, returning a string.
  See clojure.java.io/reader for a complete list of supported arguments.
```

Answer (score 3):

While slurping binary data is not possible, the following function will do something similar to `slurp` but accepts binary streams:

`(defn copy-uri-to-file [uri file]
  (with-open [in (clojure.java.io/input-stream uri)
              out (clojure.java.io/output-stream file)]
    (clojure.java.io/copy in out)))`

For this particular example the mp3 file can be downloaded like this:

`(copy-uri-to-file "http://menlochurch.podbean.com/mf/feed/5gv2gb/170219_jortberg.mp3" "foo.mp3")`

Comment: Credit: http://users.utu.fi/machra/posts/2011-08-24-2-reddit-clojure.html