# Why is image corrupted when converted to base64?

Tags: clojure, apache-commons

I'm attempting to use the following code to base64 encode an image and then email it using a third-party email service.

```
(ns application.encode
  (:import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64)
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn encode [file-path]
  (let [content (String. 
                  (Base64/encodeBase64 
                    (.getBytes 
                      (slurp (clojure.java.io/resource "public/test.gif")))))]

    ;; email file contents
)
```

However, the image is being corrupted and its size is being doubled. I'm able to verify this either by sending it via email or `spit`ting it to a local file.

What am I doing incorrectly?

UPDATE: In case it's useful, the following Ruby code does what I'm trying to do above and writing its output to a file, then `slurp`ing it allows me to send the email as desired. (This isn't a solution, of course, but I wanted to make sure what I'm trying to do was even possible using the file in question.)

`encoded = Base64.encode64(File.read('resources/public/test.gif'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, significant increase in size is expected for base64 but not exactly doubling of course.

I'm not a Clojure developer but I beliveve that the issue is aroud `slurp` + `getBytes`. Unfortunately you can't just read file as string and use `.getBytes` and expect to get original file contents because of various issues introduced by encoding. You should read file directly as bytes array. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018870/how-to-read-a-whole-binary-file-nippy-into-byte-array-in-clojure) suggest there is no such standard function but `slurp-bytes` from the second answer looks quite promising to me.

Comment: My misuse of `slurp` was indeed the cause of my problem. Using information provided by the answer you linked to, I was able to find a working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please see this closely related question and answer from this week:   [Slurping http://foobar.mp3 that redirects to http://fizzbar.mp3 in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421641/slurping-http-foobar-mp3-that-redirects-to-http-fizzbar-mp3-in-clojure)

Basically, `slurp` is for text files only.

For full information, please bookmark and keep open in a browser [tab the Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).  Also, see the specific docs [for the slurp function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp).

A nice example can be found in the Clojure Cookbook:  https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/04_local-io/4-19_handle-binary-files.asciidoc

More examples can be found on ClojureDocs:   https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/input-stream